# Add items to a state array in a loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to initialize an array with `false` values at first. I want to do it via a loop. However, the state array only updates a single time

```
componentDidMount = () => {
 const { preferences } = this.state;
 const { eventTypes } = constants;

 for (let i = 0; i < eventTypes; i += 1) {
  this.setState(state => {
    const list = preferences.concat(false);
    console.log(list);
    return { preferences: list };
  });
}
```

}

How can I concat multiple values via a loop? Or perhaps there's a more efficient way?

P.D. The `eventTypes` value might change, so making multiple `concat`s might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var size = 10
while(size--) preferences[size] = value;
```

This will return an array of 10 elements of falses.

In your case:

```
var size = eventTypes;
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, I don't know how, but it also updates the state

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    preferences: Array(eventTypes).fill(false)
  })
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's issue, it is better to add context, or an explanation as to why this solves the OP's problem, so future visitors can learn from your post, and apply this knowledge to their own issues. High Quality Answers are much more likely to be upvoted, and contribute to the value and quality of SO as a platform. You can also add a link to documentation, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:-

```
componentDidMount = () => {
 const { eventTypes } = constants;
 preferences = eventTypes.map(e => false);
 this.setState({ preferences });
}
```